# Handle view flipper animation

Tags: android

I have set setOutAnimation and setInAnimation to viewflipper. It's working perfect.
I have set 'onClick' method  of button in android layout file to flip next.

Now, what I require is Until animation won't complete,user cannot touch that button again and view flipper cannot show next view.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

//Java class for animation

```
public class MyAnimClass {

    public MyAnimClass (Context c)
    {
         ...
    }

    public void applyAnimation(Button btn){

    tAnimation.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  btn.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                  btn.setEnabled(true); 

                }
            });
       }

}
```

//Example for Activity:

```
MyAnimClass myAnim = new MyAnimClass(context);
myAnim.applyAnimation(btn1);
myAnim.applyAnimation(btn2);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have given onclick from layout xml. and I am not creating button object in java file. so I cannot use setEnabled property. any other solution.

Comment: @user861973, you can create the object of button using findViewById if you are writing animation code in activity itself. So it doesn't matter that you are giving method name in xml file. And if you are doing it using separate java class, I will suggest to pass button object as a method parameter

Comment: Yes shreya, That I understand what your are saying. but my problem is I cannot use the object because. I have multiple buttons which called same the same method.

Comment: Unfortunately It' wont' work because I need to disable the button which in next view of viewflipper. As per your suggestion I can disable only current view's button of view flipper. by d way Thanks for your efforts.